GCP & AWS: CloudFunction: Can't assume AWS role
I  created a terraform deployment for gcp cloudfunction which should assume AWS role to manipulate on AWS s3.
The problem that flow which looks like created correctly causes to (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity error.
Maybe somebody knows what I do wrongly?
requirements.txt:
google-auth
google-auth-oauthlib
google-auth-httplib2
boto3
functions-framework==3.0.0
flask>=1.0,<3.0
requests

main.py.tmpl:
from flask import jsonify

import google.auth
import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.auth import compute_engine

import boto3
import os
import traceback
import requests

def get_service_account_email():
    # Fetch the service account email from the metadata server
    metadata_url = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email'
    headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}
    response = requests.get(metadata_url, headers=headers)
    return response.text


def get_google_identity_token(audience):
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)
    return id_token


def assume_role_with_web_identity(role_arn, identity_token):
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    response = sts_client.assume_role_with_web_identity(
        RoleArn=role_arn,
        RoleSessionName='GCPAssumeRoleSession',
        WebIdentityToken=identity_token,
    )
    return response['Credentials']


def transfer_to_s3(request):
    service_account_email = get_service_account_email()
    print(f"Service Account Email: {service_account_email}")

    try:
        print("Starting the function execution...")
        role_arn = "${gcp_assume_role_arn}"

        identity_token = get_google_identity_token(service_account_email)
        credentials = assume_role_with_web_identity(role_arn, identity_token)
        print(f"Credentials were successfully assumed")

        return jsonify({
            "status": "success",
            "message": f"File {file_name} successfully transferred from GCS to S3"
        }), 200
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception: {e}\n{traceback.print_exc()}")
        return jsonify({
            "status": "error",
            "message": str(e)
        }), 500


main.tf
variable "gcp_project_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "refers to the client GCP project"
}

##############################################################################
#                                aws PROVIDER
##############################################################################
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

##############################################################################
#                                gcp PROVIDER
##############################################################################
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("${path.module}/service-account.json")
  project     = var.gcp_project_id
  region      = "us-central1"
}

##############################################################################
#                                DATA & locals
##############################################################################
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "google_project" "client-project" {
  project_id = var.gcp_project_id
}

locals {
  client_deploy_dir         = "${path.module}/deployment/"
  gcp_service_account_email = "${var.gcp_project_id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
}

##############################################################################
# AWS S3
##############################################################################
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "client-cur-gcp-bucket" {
  bucket = "client-gcp-bucket"
  force_destroy = true
}

# Enable versioning
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "client-cur-gcp-bucket-versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.client-cur-gcp-bucket.id
  # enable versionning
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

# Enable logging on s3 actioins
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "client-cur-gcp-bucket-acl" {
  bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.client-cur-gcp-bucket.id
  acl        = "private"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.client-cur-gcp-bucket-acl-ownership]
}

# Resource to avoid error "AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs"
resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "client-cur-gcp-bucket-acl-ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.client-cur-gcp-bucket.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "ObjectWriter"
  }
}

##############################################################################
# AWS Permissions for GCP
##############################################################################
resource "aws_iam_role" "gcp_assume_role" {
  name = "GCPAssumeRole"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "accounts.google.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "accounts.google.com:aud": "${local.gcp_service_account_email}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3_access_policy" {
  name = "S3AccessPolicy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.client-cur-gcp-bucket.arn}/*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_s3_access_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.gcp_assume_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_access_policy.arn
}

##############################################################################
# BUCKET FOR BigQuery results CSV
##############################################################################
resource "google_storage_bucket" "client-cloud-functions-source-bucket" {
  name     = "max-test-cloud-functions-source-bucket"
  location = "US"
  force_destroy = true
}

##############################################################################
# GCP to AWS Transfer Function
##############################################################################
# fille the template
data "template_file" "transwer-to-s3-function" {
  template = file("${path.module}/main.py.tmpl")

  vars = {
    gcp_assume_role_arn = aws_iam_role.gcp_assume_role.arn
  }
}
# save file
resource "local_file" "transwer-to-s3-function" {
  content  = data.template_file.transwer-to-s3-function.rendered
  filename = "${local.client_deploy_dir}/transwer_to_s3/main.py"
}
# zip files
resource "null_resource" "zip_transwer_to_s3_code" {
  depends_on = [local_file.transwer-to-s3-function]
  provisioner "local-exec" {    
    command = "7z a ${local.client_deploy_dir}/transwer_to_s3.zip ${abspath(local.client_deploy_dir)}/transwer_to_s3/main.py ${abspath(path.module)}/requirements.txt"
  }
}

####################
# cloud function 

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "transwer-to-s3-function-zip" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.zip_transwer_to_s3_code]
  name   = "transwer_to_s3.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.client-cloud-functions-source-bucket.name
  source = "${local.client_deploy_dir}/transwer_to_s3.zip"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "transwer-to-s3-function" {
  name                  = "transwer-to-s3-function"
  description           = "Run transwer to s3 function"
  runtime               = "python39"
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.client-cloud-functions-source-bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.transwer-to-s3-function-zip.name
  entry_point           = "transfer_to_s3"
  trigger_http          = true
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "transwer-to-s3-function-invoker" {
  project = var.gcp_project_id
  role    = "roles/pubsub.subscriber"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${local.gcp_service_account_email}"
}


CMD
you need to have your gcp service-account.json in the current dir
terraform init
terraform apply -auto-approve -var gcp_project_id=<gcp project id>



SOLUTION:
assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"Federated": "accounts.google.com"
},
"Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
"Condition": {
"StringEquals": {
"accounts.google.com:aud": "${local.gcp_service_account_email}",
}
}
}
]
}
EOF

The OP had incorrectly added their solution to the question. Posting it as an answer instead.

AWS policy should contain oaud, aud & sub fields:
assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "accounts.google.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "accounts.google.com:oaud": "${local.gcp_service_account_email}",
          "accounts.google.com:aud":  "<SA TOKEN AZP>",
          "accounts.google.com:sub":  "<SA TOKEN SUB>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF

where SA TOKEN AZP & SUB can be taken from payload with:
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
payload = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_token(token, request=request, audience=audience) 

